# Source for citing properties of solids

Tags: solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, material-science

Is there a de-facto standard (meta-)source for citing properties of solids like the "The Review of Particle Physics" is for properties of sub-atomic particles? Preferably the source should give both experimental data and properties calculated from first principles.

In my special case I want to give sources for the Curie temperatures of certain ferromagnetic materials but a source covering a wide range of other properties as well is preferred.

Comment: NIST has a decent database available in line. Curie temperatures may not be in it, but most folks cite Buschow’s paper (from the 70’s?).

Answer (score 0):

Landolt-Börnstein is a big compilation of experimental data, http://materials.springer.com/

There are several volumes about magnetic properties, for example Volume 27 ‘Magnetic properties of non-metallic inorganic compounds based on transition elements’ and Volume 32 ‘Magnetic Properties of Metals’.